# MQPUT error aborted

Tags: c, ibm-mq

Again a problem with MQPUT

Below is my function

```
#include <stdio.h>   
#include <cmqc.h>   
#include <cmqxc.h>    
#include "dte_mq.h"    
#include <string.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>    

typedef struct tagDTE_QUEUE_DESCRIPTOR    
{    
     MQHOBJ handle;    
     int    IsSyncpointControled;    
} DTE_QUEUE_DESCRIPTOR, *PDTE_QUEUE_DESCRIPTOR;    

static MQHCONN sHConn = 0;    
static MQLONG  sCompCode = MQCC_OK;    
static MQLONG  sReason = MQRC_NONE;    
static int     sNumOpenQueues = 0;    
static PDTE_QUEUE_DESCRIPTOR sQueues = NULL;    
MQLONG   OpenCode;    
MQOD     od = {MQOD_DEFAULT};    /* Object Descriptor */    
MQMD     md = {MQMD_DEFAULT};    
MQPMO    pmo = {MQPMO_DEFAULT};    
MQLONG   O_options;    
MQGMO   gmo = {MQGMO_DEFAULT};    
/* MQCONNX options */    
MQCNO   Connect_options = {MQCNO_DEFAULT};    
/* Client connection channel */     
MQCD    ClientConn = {MQCD_CLIENT_CONN_DEFAULT};    



#define MAX_NUM_OPEN_QUEUES     10    


DTE_MQ_RESULT dteMqSend(int qd, void *buf, int len)    
{    
    printf("oleg\n");    
   /* memcpy(md.Format, MQFMT_STRING, MQ_FORMAT_LENGTH); */    
   md.MsgType  = MQMT_DATAGRAM;    
   printf("oleg1\n");    
   memcpy(md.MsgId, MQMI_NONE, sizeof(md.MsgId));    
   printf("oleg2\n");    
   memcpy(md.CorrelId, MQCI_NONE, sizeof(md.CorrelId));    
   printf("oleg3\n");    
   memcpy(md.Format, MQFMT_STRING, (size_t)MQ_FORMAT_LENGTH);    
   printf("oleg4\n");    
   printf("QD is = %d\n",qd);    
  if(sQueues[qd].IsSyncpointControled)    
      pmo.Options |= MQPMO_SYNCPOINT;    
   printf("oleg5\n");    


   MQPUT(sHConn, sQueues[qd].handle, &md, &pmo, len, buf, &sCompCode, &sReason);    

   printf("MQput CC=%ld RC=%ld\n", sCompCode, sReason);    
   if (sCompCode != MQCC_OK) return DTE_MQR_FAILED;    
   return DTE_MQR_OK;    
}
```

Below is a program with function call:

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>    
#include <string.h>     
#include <cmqc.h>            /* includes for MQI          */    
#include <cmqxc.h>    


int main(int argc, char **argv)    
{    
    MQLONG   messlen;     /* message length received       */    

    char     QMgrName[MQ_Q_MGR_NAME_LENGTH+1];    
    char     QName[MQ_Q_NAME_LENGTH+1];    
    char     channelName[MQ_CHANNEL_NAME_LENGTH+1];    
    char     hostname[1024];    
    char     port[4];    
    MQLONG   buflen;    
    /* MQBYTE   TmpBuf[65536] = "This is a simple test message."; */    
    MQBYTE   TmpBuf[1024] = "This is a simple test message.";    
    int msgsToGet;    
    int msgsGot;    
    int dteretinit;    
    int dteretdeinit;    
    int dteretopen;    
    int dteretclose;    
    int qd;    
    int dteretput;    
    dteretinit = dteMqInit(QMgrName,hostname,channelName);    
    printf("Return code from dteMqInit = %d\n",dteretinit);    
    if (dteretinit == 0)    
    {    
        printf("Connection ro MQ failed, check the error log\n");    
        exit(99);    
    }    
    qd = -1;    
    dteretopen = dteMqOpen(QName, &qd);    
    printf ("Return code from dteMqOpen = %d\n",dteretopen);    
    if (dteretopen ==0)    
    {    
        printf("MQOPEN could not open MQ, check errpr log\n");    
        exit(99);    
    }    

    buflen = strlen(TmpBuf);    
    TmpBuf[buflen + 1] = '\0';
    dteretput = dteMqSend(qd,*TmpBuf,buflen);    
    printf("return mqput %d\n",dteretput);    
    if (dteretput == 0)    
    {    
        printf("Could not put the message to MQ, check error log\n");    
        exit(99);    
    }    

    dteretclose = dteMqClose(qd);    
    printf("Return code from dteMqClose = %d\n",dteretclose);    
    if (dteretclose == 0)    
    {    
        printf("Could not close MQ, check error log\n");    
        exit(99);    
    }    
    dteretdeinit = dteMqDeinit();    
    printf("Return code from dteMqDeinit = %d\n",dteretdeinit);    
    if (dteretdeinit == 0)    
    {    
        printf("Could not disconnect from MQ, check error log\n");    
        exit(99);    
    }    
}
```

The program started running, connected to MQ, open MQ, then go to send message, print all including "oleg5", and aborted

This is output:

```
Using values:    
QMgrName   : QM.SU00005    
QName      : AP.TR.FROM.ADS    
ChannelName: AVNCHCTM.CLIENT    
hostname   : enbmqu02.uk.db.com    
port       : 1415    
CC = 0, RS = 0    
Return code from dteMqInit = 1    
SAM    
SAM2    
SAM3    
MQopen = 0 and 0    
In the loop1    
QDESC1 = -990964260    
QDESC = -990964260    
Return code from dteMqOpen = 1    
oleg    
oleg1    
oleg2    
oleg3    
oleg4    
QD is = 0    
oleg5    
Aborted
```

as you can see qd=0 and in this place before MQPUT in if statement it didn't come. May be I have to make else statement and assign Options?

```
if(sQueues[qd].IsSyncpointControled)    
{    
    pmo.Options |= MQPMO_SYNCPOINT;    
    printf("Synchronized\n");    
}
```

This happened exactly on MQPUT call
Could you please help me?

Comment: What is the value of `sQueues[qd].handle`?

Comment: I don't know how to check if. qd is 0

Comment: Run the code in a debugger.  Or print out the values.  Programming is 2/3 about learning how to debug the code you write (or someone else's code).  None of what you posted is actually related to MQ.  It is straight C code and issues.

Comment: Your buffer is incorrectly referenced on the MQPUT call.

Comment: how to reference it correctly?